# Squid configuration on RHEL 6 for HTTPS

Tags: squid, rhel6

We have many client servers and a master server. In between them, there is a server (say server A) where squid is installed to act as proxy and firewall.
Clients and Server A are in one network, the master server is in a different network (internal, not via internet).
Client needs to be communicated with Master server and master needs to be communicated with client.
Server A's proxy will be configured to receive through HTTPS 8088. On client and master the port used is HTTP & HTTPS port 1000

Will the below configuration work for a connection from client to master via server A?

```
acl client src "client IP addrs.txt"
acl master dst "master IP addr.txt"
acl masterport port 1000
http_access allow client master masterport
http_port 8080
```

Do we need to mention the protocol HTTPS in the acl list?

Comment: So please explain first why they cannot communicate without proxy, since they are on the same internal network.

Comment: The servers are in different network. We want the servers to communicate through a middle man(Server A)